# Unable to flash bootloader on ATmega32U4 with AVR dragon

Tags: avr, avrdude, arduino-micro

I am flashing a *naked* ATmega32U4, but the process fails in the end where it is verifying.

```
avrdude -c dragon_isp -p m32u4 -P usb -U flash:w:Caterina-Micro.hex -U lfuse:w:0xff:m -U hfuse:w:0xd8:m -U efuse:w:0xcb:m -U lock:w:0x2f:m -v -B 100

avrdude: Version 6.1, compiled on Mar 23 2014 at 04:42:55
         Copyright (c) 2000-2005 Brian Dean, http://www.bdmicro.com/
         Copyright (c) 2007-2014 Joerg Wunsch

         System wide configuration file is "/usr/local/Cellar/avrdude/6.1/etc/avrdude.conf"
         User configuration file is "/Users/SomeUser/.avrduderc"
         User configuration file does not exist or is not a regular file, skipping

         Using Port                    : usb
         Using Programmer              : dragon_isp
         Setting bit clk period        : 100.0
avrdude: usbdev_open(): Found AVRDRAGON, serno: 00A200050468
JTAG ICE mkII sign-on message:
Communications protocol version: 1
M_MCU:
  boot-loader FW version:        255
  firmware version:              7.38
  hardware version:              1
S_MCU:
  boot-loader FW version:        255
  firmware version:              7.38
  hardware version:              7
Serial number:                   00:a2:00:05:04:68
Device ID:                       AVRDRAGON
         AVR Part                      : ATmega32U4
         Chip Erase delay              : 9000 us
         PAGEL                         : PD7
         BS2                           : PA0
         RESET disposition             : dedicated
         RETRY pulse                   : SCK
         serial program mode           : yes
         parallel program mode         : yes
         Timeout                       : 200
         StabDelay                     : 100
         CmdexeDelay                   : 25
         SyncLoops                     : 32
         ByteDelay                     : 0
         PollIndex                     : 3
         PollValue                     : 0x53
         Memory Detail                 :

                                  Block Poll               Page                       Polled
           Memory Type Mode Delay Size  Indx Paged  Size   Size #Pages MinW  MaxW   ReadBack
           ----------- ---- ----- ----- ---- ------ ------ ---- ------ ----- ----- ---------
           eeprom        65    20     4    0 no       1024    4      0  9000  9000 0x00 0x00
           flash         65     6   128    0 yes     32768  128    256  4500  4500 0x00 0x00
           lfuse          0     0     0    0 no          1    0      0  9000  9000 0x00 0x00
           hfuse          0     0     0    0 no          1    0      0  9000  9000 0x00 0x00
           efuse          0     0     0    0 no          1    0      0  9000  9000 0x00 0x00
           lock           0     0     0    0 no          1    0      0  9000  9000 0x00 0x00
           calibration    0     0     0    0 no          1    0      0     0     0 0x00 0x00
           signature      0     0     0    0 no          3    0      0     0     0 0x00 0x00

         Programmer Type : DRAGON_ISP
         Description     : Atmel AVR Dragon in ISP mode
         Vtarget         : 5.0 V
         SCK period      : 100.37 us

avrdude: AVR device initialized and ready to accept instructions

Reading | ################################################## | 100% 0.16s

avrdude: Device signature = 0x1e9587
avrdude: safemode: lfuse reads as FF
avrdude: safemode: hfuse reads as D8
avrdude: safemode: efuse reads as CB
avrdude: NOTE: "flash" memory has been specified, an erase cycle will be performed
         To disable this feature, specify the -D option.
avrdude: erasing chip
avrdude: reading input file "Caterina-Micro.hex"
avrdude: input file Caterina-Micro.hex auto detected as Intel Hex
avrdude: writing flash (32730 bytes):

Writing | ################################################## | 100% 62.28s

avrdude: 32730 bytes of flash written
avrdude: verifying flash memory against Caterina-Micro.hex:
avrdude: load data flash data from input file Caterina-Micro.hex:
avrdude: input file Caterina-Micro.hex auto detected as Intel Hex
avrdude: input file Caterina-Micro.hex contains 32730 bytes
avrdude: reading on-chip flash data:

Reading | ################################################## | 100% 152.35s

avrdude: verifying ...
avrdude: verification error, first mismatch at byte 0x0002
         0x66 != 0x6e
avrdude: verification error; content mismatch

avrdude: safemode: lfuse reads as FF
avrdude: safemode: Verify error - unable to read hfuse properly. Programmer may not be reliable.
avrdude: safemode: lfuse reads as FF
avrdude: safemode: Verify error - unable to read hfuse properly. Programmer may not be reliable.
avrdude: safemode: Sorry, reading back fuses was unreliable. I have given up and exited programming mode

avrdude done.  Thank you.
```

I get another verification error when i program without fuses:

```
avrdude -c dragon_isp -p atmega32u4 -P usb -U flash:w:Caterina-Micro.hex -u

avrdude: AVR device initialized and ready to accept instructions

Reading | ################################################## | 100% 0.16s

avrdude: Device signature = 0x1e9587
avrdude: NOTE: "flash" memory has been specified, an erase cycle will be performed
         To disable this feature, specify the -D option.
avrdude: erasing chip
avrdude: reading input file "Caterina-Micro.hex"
avrdude: input file Caterina-Micro.hex auto detected as Intel Hex
avrdude: writing flash (32730 bytes):

Writing | ################################################## | 100% 69.60s

avrdude: 32730 bytes of flash written
avrdude: verifying flash memory against Caterina-Micro.hex:
avrdude: load data flash data from input file Caterina-Micro.hex:
avrdude: input file Caterina-Micro.hex auto detected as Intel Hex
avrdude: input file Caterina-Micro.hex contains 32730 bytes
avrdude: reading on-chip flash data:

Reading | ################################################## | 100% 178.10s

avrdude: verifying ...
avrdude: verification error, first mismatch at byte 0x0000
         0x04 != 0x0c
avrdude: verification error; content mismatch

avrdude done.  Thank you.
```

Comment: can you try without setting the fuses?

Comment: Have you retried the same command several times? It can happen sometimes that the command fails due to a bad serial connection.

Comment: @Treesrule14, i tried without the fuses and the result is the same. Verification error. Although it seems like something goes right as the boards LED starts blinking. But i am absolutely not confident with the flashing.

Comment: @jfpoilpret, i have tried so many times that i stopped counting :-/

Comment: Does your board have any additional curcuitry connected to the SPI pins?

Comment: Try setting only the fuses first. By default the 32u4 runs at 1Mhz I belief. Try lowering the programming speed using `-B 10` (not sure if this works for the dragon; I have to use this parameter when programming blank AVRs using my usbASP programmer).

Comment: @ChrisStratton, yes i have and there are 100Ohm resistors between the peripheral connected.

Comment: @Gerben, i have tried setting the `-B` flag but the results are extremely inconsistent. I am afraid that the AVR dragon is not playing nicely in OSX. Tommorow i will get my hands on a Atmel-ICE and see if it will play with me.

Comment: 100 ohms may well not be enough to prevent interference with programming.

Comment: @ChrisStratton, how much is recommended?

Comment: @ChrisStratton, how much is recommended? I have MPU-9250 IMU connected to the SPI line, where there is 100Ohm resistors in series with that device.

Comment: If there is any way it could be driving signals (or clamping them? Is it powered? At what voltage?) I would want at least 1K.  Maybe best as a temporary test to remove the resistors to entirely break the connection and experiment with programming that way for an hour or two.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I literally gave up and got myself a Atmel-ICE which solved all my problems.

Answer (score 0):

I think you need to pass the option `-u` to disable safe mode, see the [avrdude documentation](http://www.nongnu.org/avrdude/user-manual/avrdude_4.html#Option-Descriptions). Under the `-u` option the manual states:

> If you want to change fuses you will need to specify this option

Comment: I tried to pass `avrdude -c dragon_isp -p m32u4 -P usb -u -U flash:w:Caterina-Micro.hex -U lfuse:w:0xff:m -U hfuse:w:0xd8:m -U efuse:w:0xcb:m -U lock:w:0x2f:m` with the `-u` option, but instead i am getting a bunch of `avrdude: stk500v2_jtagmkII_recv(): failed`. On the SPI line i also have another SPI device connected, which is _seperated_ by 100Ohm resistors, so i am not expecting that its causing any problems?

Comment: I remember getting that same error programming with the dragon via avrdude. From memory, it was due to some kind of wiring problem. Not sure about the other SPI device, but working with the simplest possible circuit will always make it easier to debug.

Comment: ISP wiring problem perhaps? The thing is that the bootloader has been uploaded to the MCU once in a while, which is quite odd if theres a wiring error.

Comment: I meant a bad connection, which may still work intermittently

Comment: I will try to change the ISP cable and see if it does anything. I have changed USB cables just to verify that its not an issue.

Comment: I have updated my post. Its as if i flash the bootloader, it is extremely hard to reflash it afterwards. Im powering it with USB.