# Unable to upload code to Leonardo

Tags: usb, arduino-leonardo, uploading, isp

I was using Arduino-Makefile to upload code to a Leonardo via its standard `make upload`. However, it became "stuck" and unresponsive, as Leonardo's sometimes do. I tried power cycling it, and unplugging the USB cable, but nothing worked. So I tried re-burning the bootloader via an AVRISP MkII programmer and the Arduino 1.8.2 IDE, but that only made things worse.

It somehow uploaded a simple "blink" program, but now the it's completely unable to be programmed via USB. When I run `make upload`, or use the Arduino IDE's "upload" button, the Leonoardo's status LED begins blinking rapidly and its `/dev/ttyACM0` device disappears permanently. I have to power-cycle it to make the device reappear, but the upload still fails, with the error:

```
/usr/share/arduino/bin/ard-reset-arduino --caterina  /dev/ttyACM0
make[1]: Leaving directory '/usr/local/myproject/main'
make do_upload
make[1]: Entering directory '/usr/local/myproject/main'
/usr/share/arduino/hardware/tools/avr/bin/avrdude -v -p atmega32u4 -C /usr/share/arduino/hardware/tools/avr/etc/avrdude.conf -D -c avr109 -b 57600 -P /dev/ttyACM0 \
        -U flash:w:build-leonardo/main.hex:i

avrdude: Version 6.3, compiled on Jan 17 2017 at 11:00:16
         Copyright (c) 2000-2005 Brian Dean, http://www.bdmicro.com/
         Copyright (c) 2007-2014 Joerg Wunsch

         System wide configuration file is "/usr/share/arduino/hardware/tools/avr/etc/avrdude.conf"
         User configuration file is "/home/chris/.avrduderc"
         User configuration file does not exist or is not a regular file, skipping

         Using Port                    : /dev/ttyACM0
         Using Programmer              : avr109
         Overriding Baud Rate          : 57600
         AVR Part                      : ATmega32U4
         Chip Erase delay              : 9000 us
         PAGEL                         : PD7
         BS2                           : PA0
         RESET disposition             : dedicated
         RETRY pulse                   : SCK
         serial program mode           : yes
         parallel program mode         : yes
         Timeout                       : 200
         StabDelay                     : 100
         CmdexeDelay                   : 25
         SyncLoops                     : 32
         ByteDelay                     : 0
         PollIndex                     : 3
         PollValue                     : 0x53
         Memory Detail                 :

                                  Block Poll               Page                       Polled
           Memory Type Mode Delay Size  Indx Paged  Size   Size #Pages MinW  MaxW   ReadBack
           ----------- ---- ----- ----- ---- ------ ------ ---- ------ ----- ----- ---------
           eeprom        65    20     4    0 no       1024    4      0  9000  9000 0x00 0x00
           flash         65     6   128    0 yes     32768  128    256  4500  4500 0x00 0x00
           lfuse          0     0     0    0 no          1    0      0  9000  9000 0x00 0x00
           hfuse          0     0     0    0 no          1    0      0  9000  9000 0x00 0x00
           efuse          0     0     0    0 no          1    0      0  9000  9000 0x00 0x00
           lock           0     0     0    0 no          1    0      0  9000  9000 0x00 0x00
           calibration    0     0     0    0 no          1    0      0     0     0 0x00 0x00
           signature      0     0     0    0 no          3    0      0     0     0 0x00 0x00

         Programmer Type : butterfly
         Description     : Atmel AppNote AVR109 Boot Loader

Connecting to programmer: .avrdude: butterfly_recv(): programmer is not responding

avrdude: butterfly_recv(): programmer is not responding
avrdude: butterfly_recv(): programmer is not responding
avrdude: butterfly_recv(): programmer is not responding
avrdude: butterfly_recv(): programmer is not responding
avrdude: butterfly_recv(): programmer is not responding
Found programmer: Id = ""; type = 
    Software Version = .; Hardware Version = �.
avrdude: butterfly_recv(): programmer is not responding
avrdude: butterfly_recv(): programmer is not responding
avrdude: error: buffered memory access not supported. Maybe it isn't
a butterfly/AVR109 but a AVR910 device?
avrdude: initialization failed, rc=-1
         Double check connections and try again, or use -F to override
         this check.

avrdude: butterfly_recv(): programmer is not responding
avrdude: error: programmer did not respond to command: leave prog mode
avrdude: butterfly_recv(): programmer is not responding
avrdude: error: programmer did not respond to command: exit bootloader
```

If I manually run:

```
/usr/share/arduino/bin/ard-reset-arduino --caterina  /dev/ttyACM0
```

or upload via the Arduino IDE, it makes the Leonardo disappear from USB, and blink rapidly. Pressing the reset button does nothing. I have to manually unplug its USB cable to fix it.

I can program it still using the AVRISP MkII programmer...but obviously that's a huge inconvenience since it takes about 5 minutes just to upload the sample blink sketch, and even then it requires that I first power off the Leonardo, disconnect the programmer, and then power on. For development, where I might need to make dozens of revisions, this turnout is far too slow.

Why am I unable to program the Leonardo via avrdude and USB?

Comment: I need to press the Leonardo's "RESET" button to get out of this state (it will always fail after the first flash failure). It works best pressing the "RESET" button when the Arduino log window shows the lines with "PORTS ..." (for example, `"PORTS {/dev/ttyACM1, } / {/dev/ttyACM1, } => {}"`).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Using some examples and similar questions, [such as this one](https://arduino.stackexchange.com/questions/8564/unable-to-flash-bootloader-on-atmega32u4-with-avr-dragon) and [this one](https://stackoverflow.com/a/5414566/247542), I fixed udev rules for the AVRISP MkII programmer, then I manually reflashed the Leonardo's bootloader with with the MkII by running:

```
avrdude -c avrispmkii -p m32u4 -P usb -B 8 -u -e -U lock:w:0x3F:m -v
avrdude -c avrispmkii -p m32u4 -P usb -v
avrdude -c avrispmkii -p m32u4 -P usb -u -U efuse:w:0xcb:m -v
avrdude -c avrispmkii -p m32u4 -P usb -u -U hfuse:w:0xd8:m -v 
avrdude -c avrispmkii -p m32u4 -P usb -u -U lfuse:w:0xFF:m -v 
avrdude -c avrispmkii -p m32u4 -P usb -U flash:w:/usr/share/arduino/hardware/arduino/avr/bootloaders/caterina/Leonardo-prod-firmware-2012-12-10.hex -v
avrdude -c avrispmkii -p m32u4 -P usb -U lock:w:0x0F:m -v
```

I'm not sure if the first and last command to write the lock bytes were necessary, since they returned the `verification error; content mismatch` error, but they didn't seem to break anything either.

Oddly, this ran in seconds, whereas the Arduino IDE took almost 5 minutes to burn the bootloader. So I suspect there's a bug in the Arduino IDE that burns an **incorrect or corrupted bootloader**.

After running this, `ard-reset-arduino` works correctly, and `make upload` can successfully upload a sketch again.

On a side note, I'm not 100% sure if `Leonardo-prod-firmware-2012-12-10.hex` was the correct bootloader to use. Again, I just made an educated guess based on naming. I'd read that the Leonardo uses the "caterina" bootloader, and the directory `/usr/share/arduino/hardware/arduino/avr/bootloaders/caterina` contained several .hex files, only three of which contained "Leonardo" in the name:

```
Caterina-Leonardo.hex
Leonardo-prod-firmware-2012-04-26.hex
Leonardo-prod-firmware-2012-12-10.hex
```

It seemed logical to not use `Leonardo-prod-firmware-2012-04-26.hex`, since that was likely an old and obsolete bootloader based on the date. That left `Caterina-Leonardo.hex` or `Leonardo-prod-firmware-2012-12-10.hex`. Unfortunately, checking the [commit logs](https://github.com/arduino/Arduino/tree/master/hardware/arduino/avr/bootloaders/caterina) shows they're exactly the same age. In my experience, `prod` tends to mean the final or production product, so I decided to try that one first and it worked. If anyone knows what `Caterina-Leonardo.hex` is for and how it differs from the others, please tell me. I don't want to risk breaking my Leonardo again experimenting with this.

The only issue I'm having now is that after I upload my sketch, with uses ROS and about 49% of the Arduino's memory, I again can no longer upload new sketches to it. I'm assuming the sketch's use of the Serial port is somehow stopping `ard-reset-arduino` from properly resetting it`. However, I the Arduino IDE is still able to upload sketches, so as a clumsy workaround, I can use that to upload the "blink" sketch, afterwhich then I can upload my own revised sketch.

Comment: If you believe this has fixed your issue please accept your own answer. Thanks!