# Which Arduinos have a true serial port?

Tags: serial, usb, arduino-leonardo

After driving myself insane with an unreliable Leonardo, I narrowed down the problem to its serial port. Namely, it's not a true serial port, but some sort of simulated monstrosity that can't be reliably reset. This makes uploading sketches immensely difficult. I found that neither Arduino-Makefile nor the Arduino IDE can reliably upload sketches to a Leonardo, and succeed only 10% of the time.

It took me awhile to accept just how terrible the Leonardo was, because before this, I had only used the Uno and Mega, which are extremely reliable. They've always "just worked" for me, so I couldn't understand why Arduino would release a board as unusable as the Leonardo. I've since realized the Uno is so reliable, in part because it has a more complete serial port, and don't use the dreaded 32u4 chip and its fake serial port that doesn't support the DTR or RST pins.

That said, which Arduino's have a real serial port? Is it only the Uno and Mega? After months of banging my head against a Leonardo, I want to avoid anything else that uses the Atmega32u4 chip. Unfortunately, looking at all the [various boards](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/List_of_Arduino_boards_and_compatible_systems), it looks like many, especially most of the newer ones, use the 32u4.

Am I missing something here? Everything I Google an error uploading with avrdude or the IDE, the results always mention problems with boards like the Leonardo and their unstable serial ports. Why does Arduino keep using the 32u4 chip if it's that unreliable?

Comment: **No** Arduinos since the Arduino Serial have a real serial port. They all leave it to the USB-UART bridge (if any) to handle anything beyond RX and TX.

Comment: Strange, I (and many others) have never had such problems with the Leonardo not the other 32U4 based boards.

Comment: Most of your question is just a rant. And your definition of a "real" serial port seem to be no native USB support. There are Arduinos with native USB support that are not 32u4 based but ARM based.

Comment: Your problems are likely caused by loading *bad sketches*.  A more productive question would focus on the means of recovering from this, ie, identifying a reliable way reset the board and stay in the bootloader to erase the bad sketch.

Comment: @ChrisStratton, I doubt it's the problem with the sketch. I was able to upload the same sketch to an Uno and didn't experience any issues. I heavily researched ways reset the Leonardo, and the near universal answer was that were was no reliable method, short of using an ISP to reflash the bootloader, which is what I did, and why I dislike the Leonardo. I expected this question to get heavily downvoted, because I know you're very defensive of these terrible boards, but I'll leave it up because I stand by my experience. Please everyone, **avoid the Leonardo like the plague.** It's a bad product.

Comment: @Cerin, I hear you. In linux, with an old Leonardo bootloader or third party bootloader, and a wrong sketch, and something called 'modemmanager' in linux, it is a real problem. In Windows and with a recent bootloader, it is working 100% okay. Do you have a programmer, and did you burn the bootloader with the Arduino IDE ? In linux, remove the 'modemmanager'. Yes, the sketch can be a problem when sending too much to the usb serial port. It could block something, preventing a restart of the bootloader.

Comment: A flawed sketch will not prevent reprogramming of an Uno; the same code on a Leonardo will prevent the logic that can intercept programming requests *after the start of a user program* from doing so.  **But it's still a badly written sketch.**

Comment: @ChrisStratton, Why is documentation of these shortcomings in the Leonardo so difficult to come by? Where's the list of **things not to do** so you don't disable your Leonardo? The Arduino community prides itself on documentation, but I found few solutions Googling this problem. Had I known it was so fragile and incompatible with Uno sketches, **I would never have bought it.** And therein lies the reason why these flaws aren't advertised...

Comment: @Jot, These problems began when I flashed the most recent bootloader using the 1.8.2 IDE. That completely disabled sketch uploading via USB. I had to manually use avrdude to flash the bootloader, [as I described here](https://arduino.stackexchange.com/questions/39927/unable-to-upload-code-to-leonardo), to restore it. What problems does `modemmanager` cause? I have the `modemmanager` package installed, but it's a service that's not running.

Comment: @Cerin - Actually Arduino documentation is notoriously, and universally, horrible in comparison to that of actual engineering components, libraries, and APIs.  In any other context, the fact that a USB stack can be broken by uncareful use of interrupt disables, clock, or I/O setting changes, or general memory corruption or execution runaway is well known.

Comment: @Cerin, remove the modemmanager.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

There seems to be quite a few Arduinos without a 32U4, like:

- Uno (you mentioned it already)
- Mega (same)
- Lilypad Snap
- MKR1000
- Pro
- Pro Mini
- Zero
- Due
- Ethernet
- Mini
- Nano
- MKR Zero

See the list at [Comparison table](https://www.arduino.cc/en/Products.Compare).